# Changing NLS_DATE_Format in Oracle Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

is it possible to change  `NLS_DATE_Format` in a function of Oracle

I have a function like this

```
   create or replace Procedure GETFLOWSHEETRESULT 
    (
....
    ) AS 

    BEGIN
    alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
    Select AVNR,Wert From E_MW_01MIN_MIT Where  DBTM='17-06-2018 16:20:00' and AVNR In (2085,2075,2089,2071);
    alter session set nls_date_format = 'DD-MON-RR';
    END GETFLOWSHEETRESULT;
```

but it gives me error:

> Error(8,4): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALTER" when expecting one of the following:     begin case declare exit for goto if loop mod null pragma    raise return select update while with       <<    close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback    savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe The symbol "update was inserted before "ALTER" to continue.

I want to change the `nls_Date_Format` before the select command. as it is per session , how can I change it?

Answer (score 4):

It's most common to translate your date string into a date value using the to_date function.

```
Select AVNR,Wert 
From E_MW_01MIN_MIT 
Where  DBTM=to_date('17-06-2018 16:20:00','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
and AVNR In (2085,2075,2089,2071);
```

If you still want to change NLS_DATE_FORMAT try:

```
execute immediate 'alter session.... ';
```

Comment: You can also use `DBMS_SESSION.SET_NLS('nls_date_format', '"DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"');`